# How to reference properties, global variable in app from other page for windows phone

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

understand that in App.Xaml.cs, I can create global variable and properties. How do I reference them from other page?? Itis ike App... something.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use:

```
(App)App.Current
```

You can also create this property in your App class, so you don't have to cast it everytime:

```
public static new App Current
{
    get { return Application.Current as App; }
}
```

With this property defined, you can reference your app just with `App.Current`

Hope it helps!