# Use a variable on NavigationService.GoBack

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

`NavigationService.GoBack()`; I'm setting a variable in viewmodel and then I want to go back, when I'm back I want to use that variable, but nothing seems to run, I don't want to refresh that page.

Any ideas?

Here i'm setting variable, and i want to go back to my MainPage.

```
void item_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {

     Button b = e.OriginalSource as Button;

     App.ViewModel.bName = b.Content.ToString();
     App.ViewModel.bID = b.Name;

     this.NavigationService.GoBack();

    }
```

Here in my MainPage i want to run the check to se if variables has changed.

```
public MainPage()

    {
      /*
i don't want to run this actually, when i'm coming back from my secondarypage.

        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeSettings();

*/

            if (App.ViewModel.bName != null)
            {
                myButton.Content = App.ViewModel.bName;
                myButton.Name = App.ViewModel.bID;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post some of your code? your question is a bit vague

Comment: Is there a posibility that the viewmodel class where your bName and bID are in, are destructed when you leave the page and go back to mainpage?  And a new instance is made of the same class, this means your vars are empty again and your result will be as well.

Comment: no that's not the issue :P see, i want to load the new values in the variables in mainpage without refreshing the whole page(mainpage)

Comment: Ah, my bad. I didn't got that out of your question. :)

Answer (score 1):

I do not have understood everything but have you tried with the "App" class to declare a variable global to all pages instead of ViewModel?

Add maybe :

Use:

```
(App)App.Current
```

From this link:
 [How to reference properties, global variable in app from other page for windows phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7155042/how-to-reference-properties-global-variable-in-app-from-other-page-for-windows)

Comment: sry my question is little vague, but i want to navigate from my mainpage to my secondarypage, then i want to go back without refreshing the mainpage, but i want to change in the mainpage.

Comment: "then i want to go back without refreshing the mainpage, but i want to change in the mainpage." Ok no problem but what do you need change in the mainpage please ?

Answer (score 1):

oh i'm sorry for the vague question, but i solved my problem.

this was needed in the mainpage.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

        if (App.ViewModel.bName != null)
        {
            myButton.Content = App.ViewModel.bName;
            myButton.Name = App.ViewModel.bID;
        }


        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    }
```

Comment: I am glad to hear that! Good luck for the future ;-)